# Change device placement of an existing tensorflow variable

Tags: tensorflow

How do I change the device placement of a tf.Variable() ?
I tried two methods

```
a = tf.Variable(1,name = 'a')  # a's device is not set
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.get_variable('a',1)
```

this creates a new variable on the gpu and doesn't change device assignment for **a**

I tried enforcing variable reuse by using

```
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
```

Here is the code :

```
a = tf.Variable(1,name = 'a')  # a's device is not set
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.get_variable('a',1)
```

this creates a new variable on the gpu and doesn't change device assignment for **a**

This time, I get an error saying the variable **a** did not exist in the gpu.

Any help on changing-device-placement or lazy-device-assignment would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's not supported, and I can't think of a hacky approach either. You could put several variables on several devices, and then copy values between them to simulate moving the variable

Comment: We've been using `tf.identity` to copy variables over, I think.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py There they remove the device placement flag from graph nodes.